# Why do we need Single() in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

Why is the main purpose of the extension method `Single()`?

I know it will throw an exception if more than an element that matches the predicate in the sequence, but **I still don't understand in which context it could be useful**.

**Edit:**
I do understand what `Single` is doing, so you don't need to explain in your question what this method does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's useful for declaratively stating

> I want the single element in the list and if more than one item matches then something is very wrong

There are many times when programs need to reduce a set of elements to the one that is interesting based an a particular predicate.  If more than one matches it indicates an error in the program.  Without the `Single` method a program would need to traverse parts of the potentially expensive list more once.

Compare

```
Item i = someCollection.Single(thePredicate);
```

To

```
Contract.Requires(someCollection.Where(thePredicate).Count() == 1);
Item i = someCollection.First(thePredicate);
```

The latter requires two statements and iterates a potentially expensive list twice.  Not good.

Note: Yes `First` is **potentially** faster because it only has to iterate the enumeration up until the first element that matches.  The rest of the elements are of no consequence.  On the other hand `Single` must consider the entire enumeration.  If multiple matches are of no consequence to your program and indicate no programming errors then yes use `First`.

Comment: I thought the 2nd 2 lines are similar to what Single does behind the scenes? It must be assessing the whole collection, that's how it knows to throw an exception for more than 1 match - but it saves you having to write that code every time. I think Single is slower than First for that exact reason?

Comment: @RichardW1001 the difference between my second code snippet and the actual `Single` implementation is the number of times the enumeration is enumerated.  In the `Single` implementation the worst case scenario is 1 time while in my code snippet the worst case scenario is 2 times.  First is **potentially** faster because it can stop enumerating the moment it sees a matching element.  So if it's the first element then the enumeration is quick.  If the matching element is the last one though then the performance of `First` and `Single` are virtually identical

Comment: @JaredPar Nice explanation. I could see the use of it in LINQ to Objects, but not in LINQ to SQL/Entities, because it is usually used in tables that have an unique field (eg. `Id`), and you will never have two values with the same `Id` because those are primary keys and you couldn't have inserted the same `Id` twice.

Comment: @Oscar I'm less familiar wit the details of LINQ to SQL so it's hard for me to comment with any certainty. My instinct is your assertion is correct.

Comment: The exact same reasoning goes for linq 2 sql. If you inspect the generated sql, you'll see that there it actually generates SELECT TOP 2, in order to be able to throw if more than one element is returned.

Comment: @JaredPar: I don't see why `Single()` is like `First()` only when the desired element is the last one. `First()` calls `MoveNext()` once, where `Single()` calls it twice to verify that it's the only element (and throws if it returns true the second time). `Single()` __never has to traverse the entire collection.__

Comment: @Allon the OP is refering to the overload of `Single` and `First` which takes a predicate expression.  That must enumerate until it finds the first element that matches the predicate

Comment: If you select by ID, and you are sure that because of database constraints, the only possible result is 0 or 1 element, then `Single` will only throw in the empty case and thus `First` is equal in this case.
But, the question was, when its useful, and not when its not. ;)

Comment: `Single` will btw. still throw if someone changed your database definition without your knowledge. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using `Single` allows you to document your expectations on the number of results, and to fail early, fail hard if they are wrong. Unless you enjoy long debugging sessions for their own sake, I'd say it's enormously useful for increasing the robustness of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Every LINQ operator returns a sequence, so an `IEnumerable<T>`. To get an actual element, you need one of the `First`, `Last` or `Single` methods - you use the latter if you know for sure the sequence only contains one element. An example would be a 1:1 ID:Name mapping in a database.

Comment: I know that, but in a `1:1` `ID:Name` relation in a database, we could use `First()` and it will be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

A Single will return a single instance of the class/object and not a collection.  Very handy when you get a single record by Id.  I never expect more than one row.